# xcode Duplicate target does not associate extension with container app

Tags: ios, xcode, imessage-extension

I have an ios app that has an imessage extension. I'm trying to create duplicated targets with a different bundle id for testing vs production. Without the imessage extension, I can just duplicate the app target and change the bundle id. When duplicating the imessage extension target however, the extension is not associated with the new container app. The only way I can find that connects the two targets is the embedded binary section of the container target. When installing the new container app to a device, the correct imessage extension is bundled with it, but I can't run the new imessage extension target from xcode. It just launches imessage and does nothing. It doesn't install the corresponding container app like the original target does. I can't find any documentation on how this works. If anyone has any advice to help, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm having the same issue with a NotificationService. Tried duplicating the target changing the necessary names/config/identifiers and what not but doesn't seem to be working for me. Particularly when using categories to show action items for a notification category.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a seperate target for the different bundle identifiers I would suggest different configurations ("Test", "QA", "Production"). You can set the bundle identifier and other settings independently for each configuration.

Afterwards create an own build scheme (copy existing one and just change the selected build configuration) for each configuration and you're ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this path already but I couldn't get xcode to find my static libraries, even after setting the search path settings to look for existing build configurations on the libraries. I guess I'll have to revisit that again

Comment: I've sometimes encountered that a few build settings get reset when copying a build configuration. So I think you are correct, maybe there is a build setting missing (which is correctly set in the "source" build configuration).